# Python DictWriter: why won't python quickly return my output file? Using Counter, csv and group-by

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, group-by, counter

I'm new to python and am trying to create a script that starts off with a sequence alignment e.g., a string of 'AAGGTTCC'.  The script should go through a file that has multiple sequences (evaluating only every second line, as the first line is just the 'sequence name'), and count the number of times the '-' symbol appears, counting, for the whole file, both the number of gaps ('-'), and their frequency.  For example:

```
SeqA
AA--GGTT-CC
SeqB
AA--GGTTC-C
```

Should produce the output:

```
1:2
2:2
```

That is, there are two gaps of size 1 and two gaps of size 2.  I decided to try to get this running by first creating a blank dictionary filled with zeros, and then replacing the zeros with the gap information in an iterative manner.  So, for the example above, the dictionary would start out as:

```
0:0
0:0
```

and then become:

```
1:2
2:2
```

after the function is run.
My script actually seems to work fine - it produces the output file that I want.  The trouble is, it works very quickly if the sequence length is 100 or even 1,000, but when I scale up to 10,000, the script produces the output file (which looks accurate) quickly, but then python keeps running (I don't know what it's doing at that point).  Since this script is part of a longer set of instructions, I need python to stop and release the output file! 
It may be something as simple as me not including a 'return' somewhere, but I've looked around a lot and am at a loss!  Any help would be much appreciated!
Here is my script:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter
import csv
import sys

my_dict = {}        # Create empty dictionary
my_new_dict = dict((el,0) for el in my_dict)    # Populate dictionary with zeros

def gap_counter(str1,filename):
    char_groups = groupby(str1, lambda char:char == '-')  # Search for '-' symbol
    counts = [len(list(group)) for char, group in char_groups]   # Extract '-' length
    summary = counts[not str1.startswith('-')::2]    
    result = Counter(summary)
    new_result = dict(result)  
    for entry in new_result.iteritems():
        my_new_dict.update(new_result)  # Update dictionary with new result
    with open(filename + ".out", 'wb') as f:     # Write final dictionary to output file
        t = csv.DictWriter(f, my_new_dict.keys())
        t.writeheader()
        t.writerow(my_new_dict)
        f.close()
    return

my_file = open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'rU')    # Run function on files in a given folder
str1 = my_file.read()
for line in str1:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        pass
    else:
        gap_counter(str1, str(sys.argv[1]))
my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-opening your output file for each line in your input! You're also reprocessing the content of your input each time. There are various ways this could be cleaned up, but the main one would be to make sure you don't have your `open` call inside a for loop.

I'm also not sure why you need a dict initialized to all zeros when you're already using a `Counter`. `Counter` is exactly the right data structure for this, no need to use both it and a dict of zeros.

I would do this something like this:

```
gap_counts = Counter()
with open(str(sys.argv[1]) + '.out', 'wb') as outfile:
    with open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'rU') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                continue
            else:
                char_groups = groupby(line, lambda char:char == '-')
                line_counts = Counter(len(list(group)) for char, group in char_groups)
                gap_counts = gap_counts + line_counts
    for key, value in sorted(gap_counts.iteritems()):
        t = csv.DictWriter(outfile, gap_counts.keys())
        t.writeheader()
        t.writerow(gap_counts)
```

I'm trusting that your `groupby` call does what you want - it looks plausible to me, but I haven't tested it. The point is that you build up a single counter, adding in the values from each line, then write it out only once.

The `with` statements don't have to be nested in each other, you could also do all the reading first, then open the output file and write to it. You could also use `itertools.ifilter` to skip the `>` lines instead of the if/else.

Also, you might want to look into the biopython third party library - it has existing tools for reading and parsing FASTA files. For instance, this approach will count incorrectly if a sequence is broken into two or more lines and splits a `--` sequence across lines. biopython's parsed sequence class won't have that problem.